# Pronunciation of plural form of words ending in "-th"

Tags: pronunciation

I have realized that to pronounce the plural form of words ending in ***-th***, we have to drop the letter "h". e.g. **Months** is pronounced /mʌnts/. But I have never seen this point mentioned in any context. I just want to make sure that this rule is correct and can be always applied.

Comment: The plural of *-nth* may be */-nts/* (or */ns/* or */-nθs/*); but *moth*, for instance, becomes */mɒðz/*.  The *n* is important.

Comment: Never mind various things you get to hear about it, many native and most non-native speakers of English, surprisingly, can and do pronounce them just the way they are spelt, e.g., /mʌnθs/.

Comment: Not checked, please take a look at this as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S-gtp08k4E

Comment: There really is no way around pronouncing the full words.

Comment: I watched it and another question just poped into my head: it seemed that he slightly dropped the \h\ sound in 'I lived here', it also happened when one of my U.S. friends said 'I loved her' or 'I've told him not to do that', I've been taught to drop some \d\ sound when it comes to past tense every so often, but never know it can go like this, I know Spanish drop \h\ all the time, I don't realize it also happens in English.

Comment: Related: [What is the rule for pronouncing the plural of short words ending with -th?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443456)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard pronunciation of a word such as *months* is /mʌnθs/, as Barrie indicated. Here the /θ/ symbol indicates the *th* sound as found at the beginning of *thin* or the end of *month*.

However, you've correctly noticed that the word *months* is not often pronounced that way, and many people do indeed say something like /mʌnts/, using /t/ rather than /θ/ for the second-to-last sound. There are two things going on here:

1. The sequence of sounds /θs/ is very difficult to say, and it is very often reduced to simple /s/, especially in rapid speech.
2. The sequence /ns/ is also somewhat difficult to say, as the transition from nasal /n/ to voiceless spirant /s/ is problematic. The letter *s* following *n* is usually pronounced as /z/; where we have an actual /s/ sound following /n/, a /t/ often gets inserted in pronunciation. For example, the word *chance* often sounds just like the word *chants*. This intrusive /t/ is called an *epenthetic consonant*.

So I believe that what's really going on here is a two-stage process:

```
θs > s    (deletion)
ns > nts  (epenthesis)
```

Both halves of this process can be frequently observed in a variety of words, while the direct change from /θ/ > /t/ is not widely attested.

This does not mean that the pronunciation /mʌnts/ is *incorrect*. It is, in fact, one of the most common spoken forms of this word, and it occurs because of normal, unobjectionable phonological processes in spoken English. You absolutely should not feel like there's anything wrong with *months* as *munts*.

Note that in any case it's very misleading to talk about "dropping the h". There is no /h/ sound anywhere in either pronunciation. The spelling convention *th* is just an orthographic convenience, and the *th* sound /θ/ has nothing to do with /h/.

Comment: I don't agree that those sequences are difficult to say. I think rather that /nts/ is difficult, or, rather, a dental followed by a dental fricative is indistinguishable from a dental followed by a dental affricate, either in articulation or in hearing.

Comment: +1: While I can believe that some people pronounce **months** as /mʌnts/, I find it hard to believe that anybody pronounces **faiths** as /feɪts/.

Comment: @Mitch: The meaning of *difficult to say* is highly subjective - and of course subtleties you personally find difficult to articulate you'll often find dificult to *discern*. I've no doubt there are some articulations that are "objectively difficult", but mostly all that matters is that *some people* have difficulty. If *everyone* had a problem with some particular sequence, we'd probably have changed the "standard" pronunciation generations ago.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm pretty certain that most if not all Caribbean speakers go for /feɪts/. I've known a few such, and they all do this.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Islands_Creole) *...in most Anglophone Caribbean dialects, in Virgin Islands Creole, dental fricatives (the "-th" sound) are often omitted from speech, and replaced by dental stops (the "-t" sound).*

Comment: Is there a minimal pair between /nts/ and /nθs/? If not, I'm not sure it's strictly appropriate to use slashes (indicating phoneme distinction) here, or talk about "would have changed the standard pronunciation" when allophones _routinely_ aren't distinguished.

Comment: @Random832: *tenths,* *tents*, and *tense.* Also maybe *absinthes* and *absence*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, but in Caribbean dialects, the change of /θ/ to /t/ is a general phenomenon, not something provoked by adjacency to /s/.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I only flagged it up because of Peter's comment, not specifically relating to /θs/. I do recall discussing /θ/ with one of my Caribbean friends who actually found it quite difficult to articulate that sound *at the end of words*. She habitually pronounced it "correctly" at the *start* of words - being naturalised British, she worked harder on that one because she thought saying *dat* for *that*, and *ting* for *thing* would mark her as uneducated. She just didn't see it that way for /θ/ at the end of words.

Comment: I have always pronounced the "th" even when there's an "s" afterwards, and I have never noticed anyone failing to do so either. Maybe it's an American thing?

Comment: Let's not forget this [classic movie scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpNgONH2ncI).

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir I have never, ever heard anyone pronounce *months* with an actual `/t/`.  Sometimes it sounds like *munce*, though.

Answer (score 10):

Where I live, ‘months’ is pronounced /mʌnθs/.

Comment: Same where I live, except that when folks are talkin fast, the vowel might rise to /ə/ and the cluster might simplify to /ns/.

Answer (score 4):

Wait, no. "months" is pronounced "munths" — the "th" has the same sound as in the singular, you just add the "s" to the end. Perhaps some dialects drop the "h", but that's not standard English. Not American English anyway.

Comment: The same in English English, for that matter. Losing the "h" is something I've only noticed in American gangster movies...

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when people pronounce the word "months" there is a process of *th* cluster simplification. The unvoiced 'TH' sound, /θ/, gets dropped.

- /mʌnθs/ ----> /mʌns/

However, if you want to make the sound for this word so that it's very native speaker-like, then you need to be careful to make the /n/ sound using your tongue behind your front top teeth. It won't sound so good if you make the sound with your tongue on the alveolar ridge (that's the little shelf behind your top teeth, where native English speakers pronounce /n/).

Occasionally, you might hear a native speaker accidentally introduce a little /t/ sound between the /n/ and the /s/. You don't need to worry about this. It just sometimes happens when speakers switch from /n/ to /s/ in normal speech.

Comment: +1, Araucaria, fascinating discipline of which I am totally ignorant. I followed your illustrations just to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Singular nouns in English that already end in unvoiced fricatives usually form plurals by adding voicing the fricative and then /z/ to then end. This is not constant across all words and speakers, but is a general trend left over from ancient forms of the language. Voicing the fricative also makes any ‘Canadian rising’ disappear, and the vowel tends to lengthen a bit compared with the singular form (not always so marked below).

- house /hʌus/ > houses /ˈhaʊzəz/
- elf /ɛlf/ > elves /ɛlvz/
- wolf /wʊlf/ > wolves /wʊlvz/
- wife /wʌif/ > wives /waɪvz/
- calf /kæf/ > calves /kævz/
- leaf /li(ː)f/ > leaves /liːvz/
- scarf /skʌɹf/ > scarves /skɑɹvz/
- bath /bæθ/ > baths /bæðz/
- moth /mɔθ/ > moths /mɔðz/
- birth /bɝθ/ > births /bɝðz/ (*I don’t know how to rightly show the height difference in those two vowels; should it be* /bɚðz/ *for the second? Somehow, I don’t think so. But the first one is a higher vowel. Compare* pert *with* bird, *for example.*)
- mouth   /mʌuθ/ > mouths   /maʊðz/
- booth /buθ/ > booths /buːðz/
- scythe /sʌiθ/ > scythes /saɪðz/
- path /pæθ/ > paths /pæðz/
- sheath /ʃi(ː)θ/ > sheaths /ʃiːðz/
- cloth /klɔθ/ > (*originally*) clothes /kloʊðz/
- oath /o(ʊ)θ/ > oaths /oʊðz/
- wreath /ɹi(ː)θ/ > wreaths /ɹiːðz/
- youth /ju(ː)θ/ > youths /juːðz/

The same thing occurs when forming the third-person singular of present tense verbs whose base forms end in fricatives.  However, verbs are much more likely to be already voiced at the end  anyway, as in the unvoiced endings of *house*, *bath*, *cloth*, *half*, and *wolf* as nouns, contrasting with the voiced endings of *house*, *bathe*, *clothe*, *halve*, and *wolve* as verbs.

However, in words like *fifth, sixth, ninth, twelfth,* and *month*, this doesn’t occur, so *month* /mʌnθ/ becomes *months* /mʌnθs/ or even /mʌns/, depending on the care of the speaker. I would say that the /θ/ is normally dropped in all but the most exacting of speech. The same sort of thing also tends to occur with the others I just mentioned, so *fifths* might be any of /fɪfθs/, /fɪθs/, or /fɪs/.

Those complex consonant clusters are all pretty much guaranteed to cause conniptions in non-native speakers whose mother tongues don’t include /θ/ — and sometimes even if they do. Both *sixths* and *twelfths* have four consonsant sounds in a row. This can be a nightmare if one’s native language doesn’t have liquid s’s, such as Spanish or Portuguese.

Comment: *Wolve* is a verb? Who says? Certainly not [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wolfed%2Cwolved%2C+wolfing%2C+wolving&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @PeterShor Quoth [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229878), but of course! "< inflectional stem of wolf n. 1. *intr.* (also with *it*). To behave like a wolf, play the wolf. 2. Of an organ: To give forth a hollow wailing sound like the howl of a wolf, from deficient wind-supply."  1st citation: 1702    C. Mather *Magnalia Christi* III. iii. ii. 187/2 — If any Seducers were let loose to ***wolve*** it among the good People of Roxbury.

Comment: @PeterShor The verb *to calve* from the noun *calf* is the same sort of thing. It’s just the way these things work, and have always worked, in English. That one even has [a first OED citation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/26563) from *c* 1000 in Ælfric’s *Homilies*. Here’s another: “1398 J. Trevisa tr. Bartholomew de Glanville *De Proprietatibus Rerum* (1495) xvii. xlix. 632 — A Hynde‥etith this herbe [diptannus] that she may calue eselier and soner.” And from 1523: “J. Fitzherbert *Bk. Husbandrie* §70 — If a cowe be fatte, whan she shall calve, than‥the calfe shall be the lesse.”

Comment: *house /hʌus/ > houses /ˈhaʊzəz/*: Not in my neck of the woods. The plural of /hʌus/ is /ˈhʌsəz/, not /ˈhaʊzəz/. The latter is sometimes used as a verb conjugation.

*/bɝθ/ > births /bɝðz/*: Again, not in my experience in the US. /bɝðz/ is a conjugated form of verb meaning "to give birth to". More than one /bɝθ/ are called /bɝθz/, homophonic to "berths".

Comment: @Spoxjox I have a friend who’s an Australian CompSci prof who was at first unbelieving, then absolutely mortified when I suggested to him that any native speaker of English anywhere pronounced the plural of *house* without voicing the first *s*. Similarly with *birth*. One always voices the final consonant for the plural noun inflections (although not for the genitive singular). One doesn’t speak of elfs or wolfs or all the rest of them. And yes, I’m a native speaker of American English from the Inland North. I don’t have the cot–caught merger, and my family are educators and professionals.

Comment: I'm brazilian, and, tchrist, I noticed you wrote " Both sixths and twelfths have four consonsant sounds in a row. This can be a nightmare if one’s native language doesn’t have liquid s’s, such as Spanish or Portuguese.". I didn't undestand what "liquid s's" mean. Could you please give further explanation for it? Thank you!

Comment: @Eros It is an *s* that doesn’t have a vowel next to it.  Compare *spike* with *espiga*.

Comment: @tchrist: I have definitely heard /ˈhaʊsəz/ from native English speakers from New England. It was very noticeable when I first moved here (I refrained from correcting them) but after living here for ten years I don't think I notice it any more. Since I didn't hear it before moving here, that means that it's not pronounced that way in California or the Atlantic seaboard south of New England.