# What is the rule for pronouncing the plural of short words ending with -th?

Tags: american-english

I've found out that with some words, the /θ/ sound becomes voiced when the *-s* suffix is added:

- path -> /pæðz/
- bath -> /bæðz/
- youth -> /juðz/
- oath -> /oʊðz/
- mouth -> /maʊðz/
- truth -> /truðz/

and with others, it doesn't:

- myth -> /mɪθs/
- breath -> /breθs/
- month -> /mʌnθs/

Is there any rule behind it, or is it by pure chance?

For native speakers: If you came across a word like that that you're not familiar with, would you be able to correctly guess the pronunciation of its plural?

Comment: They all seem the same to me.

Comment: For most Americans, these words are simply pronounced with /s/. It's possible to voice them, but it's uncommon and unnecessary. The only one you need to worry about is _houses_, which ends in /-zəz/. The distinction between /θ/ and /ð/ in English is new (since Middle English), and it still has a very low functional load (i.e, it doesn't distinguish many words), so it can be and frequently is ignored. Most English speakers don't realize there's a difference between them, for instance, because they're spelled the same way.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's interesting, because sometimes I hear Americans pronounce them with /ðz/ (especially, "paths" and "mouths"). So can you say that if I pronounced all of them with /θs/, it would sound perfectly natural?

Comment: Certainly, if you listen to them spoken, there will be slight variations from one to the other.  But if you listen to a different speaker, or even the same speaker in a different context, you will encounter different variations.  Attempting to narrow down pronunciation to the point that you can distinguish between these differences is pointless -- you're just "amplifying noise", to view it from the standpoint of an audio engineer.

Comment: That's a good way to put it, @HotLicks. And a good viewpoint for analyzing what is effectively an audio medium. This is one of those situations where the data is so noisy that you have to rely on generalizations, like phonemes and allophones. The reality is of course much messier and far less generalizable.

Comment: @JohnLawler: voicing these plurals is hardly "uncommon," but it also depends on what sound follow the word. I'd tend to devoice "hold these truths to be self-evident" but not in other environments.

Comment: In my mind, I say "baths" and "mouths" exclusively with /θ/, to distinguish from the verb form. So, for example, (in my head) "I have a hard time drawing /maʊθz/" but "He /maʊðz/ platitudes." "Paths" is the opposite, though;  I hear the plural noun voiced, and the verb "'paths" (a SF term, short for "telepaths") devoiced. It's possible that I don't actually consistently make those distinctions in speech, though. Probably I've never had occasion to say the verb "'path" out loud, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any particularly simple rule that accounts for all cases. One rule that Wikipedia gives that I have not been able to find a counterexample for is that /θs/ is always used after a consonant.

The Wikipedia article "[Pronunciation of English ⟨th⟩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8th%E2%9F%A9#Plurals)" has a (fairly under-sourced) section about plurals ending in ⟨ths⟩. It says

> Plural ⟨s⟩ after ⟨th⟩ may be realised as either /ðz/ or /θs/:
>
> - Some plural nouns ending in ⟨ths⟩, with a preceding vowel, have /ðz/, although the singulars always have /θ/; however a variant in /θs/ will be found for many of these: *baths, mouths, oaths, paths, sheaths, truths, wreaths, youths* exist in both varieties; *clothes* always has /ðz/ (if not pronounced /kloʊz/, the traditional pronunciation).
> - Others have only /θs/: *azimuths, breaths, cloths, deaths, faiths, Goths, growths, mammoths, moths, myths, smiths, sloths, zeniths,* etc. This includes all words in 'th' preceded by a consonant (*earths, hearths, lengths, months, widths,* etc.) and all numeric words, whether preceded by vowel or consonant (*fourths, fifths, sixths, sevenths, eighths* /eɪtθs/, *twelfths, fifteenths, twentieths, hundredths* /hʌndrədθs/, *thousandths*).
> - *Booth* has /ð/ in the singular and hence /ðz/ in the plural for most speakers in England. In American English, it has /θ/ in the singular and /θs/ or /ðz/ in the plural. This pronunciation also prevails in Scotland.

Another section of the article says

> In Scottish English, /θ/ is found in many words which have /ð/ further south. The phenomenon of nouns terminating in /θ/ taking plurals in /ðz/ does not occur in the north. Thus the following have /θs/: *baths, mouths* (noun), *truths.* Scottish English does have the termination /ðz/ in verb forms, however, such as *bathes, mouths* (verb), *loathes,* and also in the noun *clothes*

The *[Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology](https://books.google.com/books?id=EXlYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=plural+%C3%B0z+%CE%B8s&source=bl&ots=WO53SX1rlM&sig=BKr_o-lwk6zxpAwcP5ZUkpwEX5c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAv_Wd0djaAhVKTd8KHUH_BecQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=plural%20%C3%B0z%20%CE%B8s&f=false)* (2013), by Laurie Bauer, Rochelle Lieber, and Ingo Plag, says

> Where /θ/ is voiced to /ð/ in the formation of the plural, there is no reflection of the difference in spelling. Accordingly, there is little normative pressure on these words. [As with words ending in /f/,] we find words which have the voiced plural, words which fluctuate between the voiced and the regular plural, and words which show the regular /θ/ plural.
>
> (24) 
>   
> a. *plurals in* /ðz/: booth (for those who pronounce it with final /θ/), mouth, youth ('young man')
>   
> b. *both plurals found*: lath, oath, path, sheath, truth, wreath
>   
> c. *plurals in* /θs/: berth, birth, breath, cloth, death, depth, earth, faith, growth, heath, length, month, moth, smith, strength, tenth (*and all similar fractions*), youth ('young days'), -path, hyacinth, myth, shibboleth, zenith, *and foreign words in* -lith, -path etc.
>
> The word *bath* has in BrEng the plural /ba:ðz/ when it refers to a public swimming pool, but /ba:θs/ when it refers to domestic installations.
>
> [...]
>
> Many of the /θs/ and /ðz/ clusters are variably simplified in all but the most formal styles with the omission of the dental fricatives (and perhaps  some compensatory lengthening of the alveolar fricative)

(p. 130-131)

The authors give the example *clothes* to illustrate this last point, although I don't think that's a great example of synchronic simplification of /θs/ or /ðz/ to /s/ or /z/. A better example in my opinion is the commonly noted pronunciation of *months,* the plural of *month* /mʌn(t)θ/, as something like /mʌn(t)s/.

Answer (score 3):

How those plurals are pronounced is more likely to differ by regional accents as there is no explicit rule for saying them one way or the other.  The distinction between those sounds is unimportant in English.